# Issue with BackgroundWorker thread that crashes tree

Tags: c#, winforms

I have WinForm App with tree control. I am loading tree with XML in BackgroundWorker thread. Everything works fine with small data. But tree is crashing with big data and I am not able to trace any reason.

I am getting unhandled exception and tree is not painted on form. Some details below-

```
//object array is used for file types, path etc. 
object objArr = new object[5] { fileType, Path1, Path2, this.myWorker, returnType };
this.myWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true; 
this.myWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.CompareWorker_ProgressChanged); 
this.myWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(this.myWorker_DoWork); 
this.myWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted); 
this.myWorker.RunWorkerAsync(objArr);
```

`myWorker_DoWork` is building the tree with XML. Each node in tree is added by tree `Invoke(new AddNodes(AddNode), new object[] { isChildNode, parentNode, childNode });` inside `myWorker_DoWork`.

Comment: You are still not including the exception details in your question. It makes it extremely hard for anyone to help you if you don't provide all the details.

Comment: I'll put a 1 dollar bet on a `OutOfMemoryException`...  :-)

Comment: I observe that the problem seems to be in myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted where I am building the tree. I am thinking to move all the methods of myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted outside and call through UI Thread. How to do this effectivley? For eg. I have a method Fun() inside myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted  and I want to move out Fun() from here and call through UI Thread.

Comment: I resolved this issue by moving out all UI updates from Background thread to UI thread. That's always good practice to perform business logic in background tread and update your UI controls in UI thread. This will never cause any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by moving out all UI updates from Background thread to UI thread. That's always good practice to perform business logic in background thread and update your UI controls in UI thread. This will never cause any issue.